# Please guys what might the cause of this error am recieving

Tags: python, outliers, eda

TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [NoneType]

###I receive this error whenever i run this code.

print(df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))

Please what am I not doing right?

Comment: Make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this error.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is no legal boolean operator in python. You should use the keyword „`or`“ instead.

////////////////

```
print(df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) or df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your parenthesis but Did you try to use `or` instead of `|`

**btw:** you can debug your code by printing each statement alone and see whats not right, something like this:

```
n1 = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
print(df < n1)
n2 = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
print(df > n2)

print(df < n1 or df > n2)
```

Comment: You are number 1 . Thanks very much. i change it to or , and it works

Comment: @ojicletus Your welcome mate, btw you can `accept` the answer if it works.